# How can I join two data frames in R on a common column and grab the last value in case of a repeated row?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames, suppose:

c`at = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c('a','b','c'))`

and

```
bat = data.frame(a=c(1,2,2,3), r=c('z','x','w','y'))
```

and I want to merge these two frames on the common column 'a' but I want to take from the second data frame only the last entry in case of duplicates..so in this case I would want the row with 'w'. What is a good way to do that? Preferably without resorting to a secondary package like plyr or data.table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean something like this

```
> df <- merge(cat, bat)
> df[!duplicated(df$a, fromLast = TRUE), ]
  a b r
1 1 a z
3 2 b w
4 3 c y
```